# PHP version 5.2.3 and Twilio, issues with sending SMS

Tags: php, sms, twilio

I'm having a bit of trouble sending SMS on my web application using PHP Version 5.2.3 (I have been asked not to update the version).

I have tried the same code on my local php server (which works fine), which uses 5.5.14. That code is:

```
<?php
    require 'twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';
    $account_sid = 'sadasdasd123'; 
    $auth_token = 'sdfsdfdsfds678'; 
    $client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 
    try {
        $message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
            "From" => "1234567890",
            "To" => "9876543211",
            "Body" => "Test message!"
        ));
    } catch (Services_Twilio_RestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo "Sent message {$message->sid}";
?>
```

According to the [Twilio PHP documentation](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php), 5.2.3 is the minimum version you can use.

Any ideas on this issue are greatly appreciated. As stated, I **cannot** update the PHP 5.2.3 version.

Comment: What are the errors? and do you see value for $message->sid?

Comment: None. Doesn't even hit the catch block. The page breaks when the try block tries to execute (I put echos all over the place to see where it broke).

Comment: So you probably get 500 eror. Check your server logs.

Comment: When I sent SMS using twilio, I used $client->account->sms_messages->create(...)

Comment: For sure, tried both. Will let you know on server logs.

Comment: I noticed you have not added "+1" to the numbers in From & To, please add +1 in the start of number and try again

Answer (score 0):

They have updated their documentation and recently i faced this issue so after research i was able to sending sms and writing the steps you should follow and it would work.

```
Download    [https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/archive/master.zip][1]
Refernce    [https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages][1]

require_once("/path/Twilio.php");

$client     =       new Services_Twilio(ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN);
$sms_from   =       "+1XXXXXXXXXX";
$sms_to     =       "+1XXXXXXXXXX";
$sms_body   =       "test Message";
$message    =       $client->account->messages->sendMessage($sms_from, $sms_to, $sms_body);

echo "<pre>"; print_r($message); echo "</pre>";
```

It should work on 5.2.3

Comment: Hi Naveed. Thanks for the answer. Still no go though. The site I'm trying to get this working on is our company intranet, which doesn't use https, just http. I'm wondering if that may be an issue?

Comment: Yes as twilio base url used https. Ask your system administrator to allow twilio site so you can get it work. Code is 100% tested and functional.

Comment: Ok would it be something as simple as https://www.twilio.com? Or what url should I tell the SysAdmin to allow?

Comment: Great thanks, will try this shortly and let you know.